# Repeat data frame, with varying column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame and need to repeat the values for a set of values. That is, given

```
test3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':[1, 2, 3, 4, pd.np.nan], 'y':['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']})
test3
    x  y
0   1  a
1   2  a
2   3  a
3   4  b
4 NaN  b
```

I need to do something like this, but more performant:

```
test3['group'] = np.NaN
groups = ['a', 'b']
dfs = []
for group in groups:
       temp = test3.copy()
       temp['group'] = group 
       dfs.append(temp)
pd.concat(dfs)
```

That is, the expected output is:

```
    x  y group
0   1  a     a
1   2  a     a
2   3  a     a
3   4  b     a
4 NaN  b     a
0   1  a     b
1   2  a     b
2   3  a     b
3   4  b     b
4 NaN  b     b
```

Comment: This looks like it is working to me.  What exactly are you expecting to be different?

Comment: @tnknepp something more efficient, perhaps vectorized.